# Flutter No Products for In-App-Subscriptions query

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-developers-console

Hi I tried everything to query/retrieve subscriptions with Flutter using the official [`in_app_purchase`](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package but I don't get them.

Everything works fine with iOS. With the same code on Android, it doesn't work.

This is what I get in the console

> Purchase etf_info_access_subscription not found

```dart
class IAPConnection {
  static InAppPurchase? _instance;
  static set instance(InAppPurchase value) {
    _instance = value;
  }

  static InAppPurchase get instance {
    _instance ??= InAppPurchase.instance;
    return _instance!;
  }
}

class SubscriptionsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<PurchasableProduct> products = [];
  List<PastPurchase> purchases = [];

  StoreState storeState = StoreState.loading;

  final iapConnection = IAPConnection.instance;

  SubscriptionsProvider() {
    loadPurchases();
  }

Future<void> loadPurchases() async {
    final available = await iapConnection.isAvailable();
    if (!available) {
      storeState = StoreState.notAvailable;
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }
    final serverAvailable =
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        await NetworkService.instance.testServerAvailability();
    if (serverAvailable == false) {
      storeState = StoreState.notAvailable;
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }
    const ids = <String>{storeKeySubscription}; // which is 'etf_info_access_subscription'
    final response = await iapConnection.queryProductDetails(ids);
    for (var element in response.notFoundIDs) {
      debugPrint('Purchase $element not found'); // I always get this printed in Android :(
    }
    products =
        response.productDetails.map((e) => PurchasableProduct(e)).toList();
    debugPrint(products.toString()); // Always empty
    storeState = StoreState.available;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

These are the dependencies in /app/build.gradle

```
def billing_version = "5.0.0"

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version")
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

I also uploaded a build with these onto the play store closed and internal testing successfully but still I can't retrieve products...

I have also created a subscription with the same ID as the app:

[image]

Comment: I have build everything and it is working with iOS. The only missing is Android which I can't query the Products which makes no sense. @Georgina

Comment: That's no solution. I can't make the whole thing up again for android. I have set up everything. @Georgina

Comment: I had the same issue, found this question, and wanted to share my solution, even though the problem was different. My debug Android version used a `applicationIdSuffix`, which I think resulted in it not searching for the production products (since I only have one app in the store). Once I built for release, the products returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that can cause this so hard to say exactly but the first things to check are that:

1. Your app is **published** on a closed track and you've added a tester. A lot of times developers will try to test before the app is published to a closed track.
2. The subscription product is in the Active state in the Play Console.
3. You need to join the testers program in the closed and internal track.

There is a helpful article here screenshots and other reasons why this can happen on iOS and Android: https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/why-are-offerings-or-products-empty-124

Comment: Like I said it is published already in the closed track. I am using the real device with my google email that I have added as a tester to use the app. Using the testers link will result in a not found website.

Comment: And the products are active

Comment: >Using the testers link will result in a not found website.
This sounds like the problem - your testers haven't opted into testing if the link doesn't work. The Google docs state it can take a few hours to become available for testers so maybe it's a propagation thing. Also the opt-in link won't show if app is in "Draft" or "Pending publication" state.

Comment: My app isn't published to the public. It's still in the dev stage. How can this link even be accessible? It's not a special invite link. It's only a link to my Google PlayStore page which is not found because I haven't published the app to the public. It makes no sense to publish an app completely to the public to be able to access or test in app subscriptions

Comment: Ok I see the tester had to join the testing program for it to work. It was the second link at the bottom. But now when I tap to buy it says: "The requested item cannot be purchased"

Comment: App release could be a concern in few cases. 
I facing this issue with `revenue-cat-react-native-sdk` . It works smooth with IOS store but with google play store it throws an error